# Sorting evens and odds

Tags: java, arrays

Modify the parameter array so it still contains the exact same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that all the even numbers come before all the odd numbers. Other than that, the numbers can be in any order. You must modify the array arguments by changing array in method evensLeft. The array may be empty or have only one element. In both cases, no change should be made.

```
public void evensLeft(int[] array){
      int j = array.length-1;
      int h = 0;
      int[] newArray=array;
      for (int k = 0; k < newArray.length; k++) {
        if(newArray[k]%2==0){
            array[h]=newArray[k];
            h++;
        }else{
            array[j]=newArray[k];
            j--;
        }
    }
  }
```

My tests aren't passing and i can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line `int[] newArray=array;`

You should copy `array` to `newArray` but `int[] newArray=array;` is simply making `newArray` to reference an array of integers that `array` is referencing.

Change your code to `int[] newArray=array.clone();` to copy the integer array, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Copying link to the array, has no meaning, since you will still be modifying original array

> ```
>    int[] newArray=array;
> ```

use

> ```
>    java.util.Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something using Comparator.

```
Set<Integer> ts=new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                if(o1%2==0){

                    if(o2%2==0){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return -1;
                }else if(o2%2==0){
                    return 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }
        });
        ts.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2,1,5,7,8,3}));


        System.out.println(ts);
```

**Output:**

[8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3]